# Fail to Copy and Paste feature class

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, file-geodatabase, feature-class, copy

I am trying to copy a polygon feature class from a sde geodatabase and paste it into a file geodatabase but got the message saying "Failed to paste XXX A row with this OID already exists". No same feature class is in the file geodatabase. Also I can copy and paste another line feature class from the same sde gdb to the same file gdb with no problem. Anyone has a clue?

Comment: The error message is quite specific.  There are a number of other mechanisms for transferring data that don't attempt to preserve OIDs.  I suggest you try one of them